# How do you set a flash message in the template in Craft 3?

Tags: craft3

How does one set a flash message in the templates? I can't find any documentation about this, only for plugins or getting the message.

My use-case is, I am checking if a user is allowed to access a certain page and if they cannot I want to set a flash message, then redirect them to another page. I prefer this than to keep them on the same page and is if else logic to show the message or the rest of the page.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to set a flash message from the template, however this might be a nice improvement for the `{% redirect %}` tag.

Comment: Now (Craft 3.1) you can set a notice/error message with the `{% redirect %}` tag: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/tags/redirect.html#flash-messages

Comment: redirect with flash notice is great. I had not found that documentation because its within the redirect documentation, whereas I had been searching for flash and did not find this page! Thanks.

Comment: Laurence, it was added to the docs yesterday, along with the Craft 3.1 release ;-) https://github.com/craftcms/cms/pull/3625

Answer (score 13):

You can set [flash messages](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-sessions-cookies#flash-data) using [yii\web\Session::setFlash()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-session#setFlash()-detail).

The `session` component is available to templates via `craft.app.session`.

```
{% do craft.app.session.setFlash('error', 'You’re not allowed to go there.') %}
```

For convenience, Craft’s [SessionBehavior](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-behaviors-sessionbehavior.html) class adds shortcut [setError()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-behaviors-sessionbehavior.html#method-seterror) and [setNotice()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-behaviors-sessionbehavior.html#method-setnotice) methods to the `session` component as well.

```
{% do craft.app.session.setError('You’re not allowed to go there.') %}
```

You can place that right before your `{% redirect %}` tag.

Answer (score 10):

**Edit: Brandon replied as I was writing this. Feel free to remove :)**

You can do that using this in your conditional, just above your redirect tag

```
{% do craft.app.session.setFlash('error', 'no no no') %}
{% redirect "tosomewhere" %}
```

Then in the template you are redirecting to

```
{% set message = craft.app.session.getFlash('error', null, true) %}
{% if message %}
    {{ message }}
{% endif %}
```