# How to find if there is a draft for a particular entry in control panel plugin

Tags: craft3, control-panel

I am trying to display a notification to the user in CP, if the entry is having a draft so that the next user won't redo/overdo the other draft. For that how do we find the entry has drafts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`\craft\services\Drafts::getEditableDrafts`](https://%20getEditableDrafts) to find drafts that the user can edit for the given entry:

```php
$drafts = Craft::$app->getDrafts()->getEditableDrafts($entry);
```

If you want to bypass the permission check and find *any* drafts for the entry, regardless of permissions and current user, you can use an entry query. Use [`draftOf`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/entries.html#draftof) to limit the query to drafts of the given entry and [`status(null)`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/entries.html#status) to allow the query to return drafts:

```php
$drafts = Entry::find()
    ->draftOf($entry)
    ->siteId($entry->siteId)
    ->status(null)
    ->orderBy(['dateUpdated' => SORT_DESC])
    ->all();
```

This will always return an array of drafts, which may be empty if there aren't any. If all you care about is whether a draft exists, you can execute the query with `exists()` instead of `all()`, which will just return a boolean `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the details in addition to the above, could you point me to how to display an html notification on the control panel?

Comment: @Parthiban Craft refers to those notifications as _flash messages_, you can set them through the session component. See [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/29094/how-do-you-set-a-flash-message-in-the-template-in-craft-3) and [here](https://craftquest.io/lessons/using-flash-messages-in-craft-and-twig) for details.

Comment: Thanks, @moritzlost But the above solutions won't display permanently(after certain seconds it will auto-hide). I was looking to show a notification permanently. Currently, I append HTML elements with JS. Let me know if there are any specific notification methods we can use.

Comment: @Parthiban In Craft 4 there's a new setting for the default duration that flash messages are visible for, you can set the `notificationDuration` as part of the `accessibilityDefaults`. You can set that to `0` to show the messages indefinitely, though users can still change that in their account. That setting is only available in the latest Craft 4 version, though. I don't think there's another convenient method for this, so appending messages in JS sounds reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for the details @moritzlost